# Fitting of interatomic potentials to a training set

Tags: quantum-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

I have read several times in the literature the following:

"The fittings were accomplished using a combination of the singular value decomposition method for linear parameters and the Simplex method for nonlinear parameters."

What I understand from it is that the non-linear parameters are optimized iteratively and for each choice new optimized linear parameters have to be computed. In other words, the full optimization of all parameters therefore entails a linear optimization nested in a non-linear one.

I'm planing to implement this on my own code, although How can I justify this procedure?, is there any reference or book that you could recommend me for reading??

Lets take, for instance, the Buckingham potential

$\Phi _{{12}}(r)=A\exp \left(-Br\right)-{\frac  {C}{r^{6}}}$

Comment: for non-linear, dependent parameters you may consider global optimization techniques (genetic algorithms, monte carlo basin hopping, particle-swarm, etc.)

Comment: It has been suggested that this question might be appropriate on [scicomp.SE].  I have no problem with moving it there, but I will give you the choice.